# Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object (P4A application Framework)

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm trying to make Widgets using P4A Application framework and i have a reflectively sound code up to the last mask, This should make a widget that produces gives the user the ability to move to another mask which should perform a different function, the error origionates from line 28 where the code is;

```
->load($this->locations);
```

I believe its extending the class but i am unsure, any help... the rest of the code is as follows

```
class main_dashboard_mask extends P4A_Base_Mask
{

public $locations = array(
        array('value'=>'area1','description'=>'area one'),
        array('value'=>'area2','description'=>'area two'),
        array('value'=>'area3','description'=>'area three'),            
        );
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $p4a = p4a::singleton();
    $this->setTitle("Dashboard");

    $this->build('p4a_field','MeetingRooms');
    $this->MeetingRooms->setLabel("This is the meeting room label");
    $this->build('p4a_button', 'continue')
    ->setLabel('Continue?')
    ->implement("onclick", $this, "change");
   $this->build('p4a_field','booking')
    ->setlabel('Viewing?')
    ->setType('checkbox')
    ->setValue(true);
    $this->booking->label->setTooltip('If you are booking a meeting room, check this box');

    $this->build("P4A_Array_Source", "location")
    ->getPk("value")
    ->load($this->locations);
    $this->build('p4a_field','location')
    ->setLabel('location')
    ->setValue('area1')
    ->setType('select')
    ->setSource($this->location)
    ->setWidth(60);
    $this->weight->label->setWidth(60);
    $this->MeetingRooms();
}

private function MeetingRooms()
{
    $this->build('P4A_fieldset', 'widgetframe')
    ->anchor($this->location)
    ->anchorLeft($this->booking)
    ->anchorLeft($this->continue)
    ->setLabel('Meeting Room Bookings');
}

}
```

any help would be appreciated =].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay try this, it might be better for you.

here's the code:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setTitle("Dashboard");

    $this->build('p4a_field','MeetingRooms');
    $this->MeetingRooms->setLabel("This is the meeting room label");
    $this->build('p4a_button', 'continue')
    ->setLabel('Continue?')
    ->implement("onclick", $this, "change");

   $this->build('p4a_field','booking')
    ->setlabel('Booking?')
    ->setType('checkbox')
    ->setValue(false);

    $this->booking->label->setTooltip('If you are booking a meeting room, check this box');



    $this->build("p4a_db_source", "login")
    ->setTable("meetingrooms")
    ->load()
    ->firstRow();

    $this->build('p4a_field','location')
    ->setSource($this->login)
    ->setLabel('location')
    ->setType('select')
    ->setSourceValueField("position")
    ->setSourceDescriptionField("MeetingRoom")
    ->setWidth(120);


    $this->build("p4a_fieldset","Book")
    ->anchor($this->location)
    ->anchor($this->booking)
    ->anchor($this->continue)
    ->setLabel('Meeting room bookings');

    $this->display("main",$this->Book);


}


}
```

good luck :)
thanks for accepting my brilliance xx

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the class reference and code, `P4A_Data_Source::getPk()` returns a string, not an object which is why you are getting the error.  By default it looks like the value of the PK is `NULL` which  would guess you are getting back.  Also the `getPk` method doesn't appear to accept any argumens.

You could fix this by chaining in a different order:

```
$this->build("P4A_Array_Source", "location")
     ->load($this->locations)
     ->getPk();
```

This looks like the correct thing since calling `load()` sets the PK.

Comment: I tried this, the error is still the same, i believe it is to do with the class extension, i will  look into the p4a resources now to check...

Comment: I have less of an answer and more of a way around the issue, by using MySQL i'm hoping to do the same function, but with a cleaner code and less errors, i'm just working it out on my project and i will post it as an answer (it answers the problem i'm having, not the problem i stated).